# Website not allowing to extract data using python

Tags: python, web-scraping

I am trying to extract data from a webpage (https://clinicaltrials.gov), I have built a scraper using selenium and lxml and it is working fine. I need to hit the next page button once the first page scraping is done, after going to the next page I need to take the url of that page using (driver.current_url) and start the scraping again.

Here the problem is search results table only changing but the URL remaining same. So whenever driver taking current url (driver.current_url) first page results coming again and again.

Edited:
here is the code

```
import re
import time
import urllib.parse
import lxml.html
import pandas as pd
import requests
import urllib3
from lxml import etree
from lxml import html
from pandas import ExcelFile
from pandas import ExcelWriter
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
import selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions as EC

siteurl = 'https://clinicaltrials.gov/'
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get(siteurl)
WebDriverWait(driver, 5)
driver.maximize_window()

def advancesearch():
    driver.find_element_by_link_text('Advanced Search').click()
    driver.find_element_by_id('StartDateStart').send_keys('01/01/2016')
    driver.find_element_by_id('StartDateEnd').send_keys('12/30/2020')
    webdriver.ActionChains(driver).send_keys(Keys.ENTER).perform()
    time.sleep(3)

driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[contains(@id, 'home-search-condition-query')]").send_keys('medicine') #Give keyword here
advancesearch()
#driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[contains(@class, 'dataTables_length')]//label//select//option[4]").click()
#time.sleep(8)

def nextbutton():
    driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")
    time.sleep(5)
    driver.find_element_by_xpath("//a[contains(@class, 'paginate_button next')]").click()

def extractor():
    cur_url = driver.current_url
    read_url = requests.get(cur_url)
    souptree = html.fromstring(read_url.content)
    tburl = souptree.xpath("//table[contains(@id, 'theDataTable')]//tbody//tr//td[4]//a//@href")
    for tbu in tburl:
        allurl = []
        allurl.append(urllib.parse.urljoin(siteurl, tbu))
        for tb in allurl:
            get_url = requests.get(tb)
            get_soup = html.fromstring(get_url.content)
            pattern = re.compile("^\s+|\s*,\s*|\s+$")
            name = get_soup.xpath('//td[@headers="contactName"]//text()')
            phone = get_soup.xpath('//td[@headers="contactPhone"]//text()')
            mail = get_soup.xpath('//td[@headers="contactEmail"]//a//text()')
            artitle = get_soup.xpath('//td[@headers="contactEmail"]//a//@href')
            artit = ([x for x in pattern.split(str(artitle)) if x][-1])
            title = artit[:-2]
            for (names, phones, mails) in zip(name, phone, mail):
                fullname = names[9:]
                print(fullname, phones, mails, title, sep='\t')

while True:
    extractor()
    nextbutton()
```

Comment: Is there pagination element present ?

Comment: Yes, I am hitting the next button and it is going to the next page, but URL not changing. That is the problem

Comment: okey. If you get next page, try to access element using xpath in browser "$x('//*[@id="theDataTable"]/tbody/tr[1]/td[4]/a')[0].click()" for testing

Comment: If you getting dom elements of next page, then why you hit current url again?

Comment: I am taking current URL and formatting it using lxml-html, the xpath which you are suggesting is working, but the problem is same URL driver taking again and again.

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a [mcve]

Comment: @QHarr, hi sir i have edited the question with code, kindly check

Comment: Any reason you can't use the API (https://clinicaltrials.gov/api/gui) or request the data (https://clinicaltrials.gov/ct2/resources/download#DownloadAllData)?

Comment: I have checked and VTR (voted up and to re-open).

Comment: @xbello, we'll not get mail id's and phone numbers using those API and downloaded XML file also not having those details

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a number of changes (for example, use shorter less fragile css selectors and bs4) I would probably make but the two that stand out:

1) You already have the data you need so there is no requirement for a new url. Simply use the current page_source of driver.

So top of extractor function becomes

```
def extractor():
    souptree = html.fromstring(driver.page_source)
    tburl = souptree.xpath("//table[contains(@id, 'theDataTable')]//tbody//tr//td[4]//a//@href")
    #rest of code
```

2) To reduce iterations I would set results count to 100 at start

```
def advancesearch():
    driver.find_element_by_link_text('Advanced Search').click()
    driver.find_element_by_id('StartDateStart').send_keys('01/01/2016')
    driver.find_element_by_id('StartDateEnd').send_keys('12/30/2020')
    webdriver.ActionChains(driver).send_keys(Keys.ENTER).perform()
    time.sleep(3)
    WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "#theDataTable_length [value='100']"))).click() #change for 100 results so less looping
```

then add additional import of

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to get the URL if the page it's already change. 
You could start re-iterating from when the page has reloaded after you click next. You can make the driver wait until an element is present (*explicit wait*) or just wait (*implicit wait*).